# Any condition in Jenkins for Build Periodically do build only when changes found

Tags: jenkins, cron, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I am using build periodically option schedule `H 23 * * *`

Would last have run at Friday, January 19, 2018 11:17:51 PM EST; would next run at Saturday, January 20, 2018 11:17:51 PM EST.

This is triggered everyday even when changes are not found. How can I make build periodically be triggered only when modifications are found?

Here in my case not using any version controls only nexus repository

Please let me know the solution that would be great....

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can set Jenkins to `Poll SCM` which means it will check whatever Source Control Management you are using (eg. Git or SVN) for changes and perform a build only if changes are found.

This [blog post](http://www.andyfrench.info/2015/03/automatically-triggering-jenkins-build.html) has some great screenshots and more information on how to set this up.

Comment: Not using any version controls only nexus repository in that case how we can do

Comment: In my case not using any version controls Jenkins Job will get a package from nexus repo

Comment: This may be of help to you in that case https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/URLTrigger+Plugin mentioned is the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31317469/8292297

Comment: Thanks for that will try with these option

Comment: Will that check the content of zip file also